# jQuery: Unbind event handlers to bind them again later

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Does anybody know how to unbind set of event handlers, but memorize them in order to bind them again later? Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you events have a same handler function?  or all different.

Comment: it shouldn't be the matter. Lets pretend they all are different and I don't know what are they

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a events element in the data of the item.  This should get your started, you can read your elements and store the handlers in an array before unbinding.  Comment if you need more help.  I got this idea from reading the $.fn.clone method so take a look at that as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').click(function(e) {
        alert('test');
        var events = $('#test').data("events");
        $('#test').unbind('click', events.click[0]);
    });
});

<a id="test">test</a>
```

Comment: I was also looking around the solution for this problem, and this answer works greatly. For more generality, you could access events.click via an iterator.

Comment: In jQuery 1.4.2, they changed how events are stored, so this won't work: http://blog.jquery.com/2010/02/19/jquery-142-released/ .  I'm not sure what you have to do instead.

Comment: To handle post-1.4.2 bindings, see the post on namespacing events, below.

Answer (score 8):

Here is how to achieve that, provides a `storeEvents` and a `restoreEvents` methods on a selection. `storeEvents` takes a snapshot of the events on the moment it is called. `restoreEvents` restores to the last previous snapshot. Might need to twist it a little for parameterizing the unbinding while restoring, maybe you'd like to keep the bound events after the last snapshot.

```
(function($){

    function obj_copy(obj){
            var out = {};
        for (i in obj) {
            if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
                out[i] = this.copy(obj[i]);
            }
            else
                out[i] = obj[i];
        }
        return out;
    }


    $.fn.extend({

        storeEvents:function(){
            this.each(function(){
                $.data(this,'storedEvents',obj_copy($(this).data('events')));
            });
            return this;
        },

        restoreEvents:function(){
            this.each(function(){
                var events = $.data(this,'storedEvents');
                if (events){
                    $(this).unbind();
                    for (var type in events){
                        for (var handler in events[type]){
                            $.event.add(
                                this, 
                                type, 
                                events[type][handler], 
                                events[type][handler].data);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            return this;
        }

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 8):

Since jQuery 1.4.2+ changes how event handlers are stored, this seems relevant:

The best way I found was to use event namespacing:

```
var ary_handlers = [ fn_highlight, fn_onpress, fn_cleanup ];
for ( idx = 0; idx < ary_handlers.length; idx++ ){
  $('#test').bind('click.foobar',ary_handlers[idx]);
}

// and then later: 
$('#test').unbind('.foobar');
```

In the above example, all foobar events unbound.  Notice that if you needed finer grain control, you could namespace each click handler and correlate to your array of handlers:

```
var ary_handlers = [ fn_highlight, fn_onpress, fn_cleanup ];
for ( idx = 0; idx < ary_handlers.length; idx++ ){
  $('#test').bind('click.ns_' + String(idx), ary_handlers[idx]);
}

// and then later you could pick off a specific one to unbind
$('#test').unbind('.ns_2');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a jQuery plugin called [Copy Events](https://plugins.jquery.com/copyevents/), which copies events from one object to another. This could very easily be used to "save" events from one element and bring them back later. Just one more option :)

Edit: fixed broken link

Answer (score 0):

In order to unbind an event handler you need to pass the handler function into unbind(). So you already have the handler function, all you have to do is remember it.

Comment: I thought if you do not pass a specific handler function, unbind applies to all events for that object?

Comment: @Helmut yes `unbind` will unbind all handlers if you call it with no arguments. You will not be able to bind them again later unless you have kept a reference to them. You may also unbind events that you are unaware of - e.g bound by another script. It is best to call unbind with a specific handler so that you can be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **`event.handler`** parameter:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('test');
        $('#test').unbind('click', e.handler);
        //Do Something...
        $('#test').click();
    });
});

<a id="test">test</a>
```

`event.handler` returns the current handler that has received the event, So by omitting it you could keep the other handlers.

Answer (score -3):

Nick Craver appears to have the [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2519061/39396) for jQuery 1.4.2+.  He also includes a helpful [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/968jj/).  His solution allows you to retrieve all event handlers attached to a jQuery element and to figure out which handler they were attached to.

Comment: People who down vote should provide the reason they down vote.  Helps the person learn and provides a bit of accountability...sometimes the down voter is wrong.  Everybody learns.