# jQuery: Can I get a reference to the bound events on an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some elements with a function bound to the `click` event. I want to bind that same function instead to the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events. Is it possible to get a reference to the click event so that I can assign it to those other events? I'm imagining something like this (inside `each()`):

```
$(this).bind('mouseover', $(this).click());
$(this).bind('mouseout', $(this).click());
$(this).unbind('click');
```

**Questions You Might Ask**

*Why don't you just change the code that's binding it to the click event?*

The JS that's setting this up is part of a Drupal module ([DHTML Menu](http://drupal.org/project/dhtml_menu), if you're curious), so I don't want to change the module code because it will be wiped out when the module is inevitably updated in the future. I'm also using the `click` handler for other parts of the page - I only want to move it to `mouseover` and `mouseout` for one menu.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516265/jquery-unbind-event-handlers-to-bind-them-again-later .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In jQuery, all the events bound by jQuery are stored in `data` under the key `events`. The following would do what you want:

```
var $this = $(this),
    events = $this.data('events');
if( events && events['click'] ){
  // Loop through each click event bound to this control
  $.each( events['click'], function(){
   // this = the function
   $this.bind('mouseover mouseout', this);
  });
  // Finally, remove all `click` handlers with one call
  $this.unbind('click');
}
```

Comment: Just for other's future reference, this has been dropped in jquery 1.8. .data('events') isn't available.

Comment: in jquery 1.8, you can still access the events dictionary with `$._data(element, "events")`, but that may change at any time.

Comment: What if I want to find all the events bound not only by jQuery but other methods/process also.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
jQuery('#element').data('events');
```

You can also do this:

```
jQuery.each(jQuery('#element').data('events'), function(i, event){
    jQuery.each(event, function(i, eventHandler){
        console.log("The handler is " + eventHandler.toString() );
    });
});
```