# Find out the registered methods for OnClick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple input element :

```
  <input class="a" />     // <---notice - no inline onclick function
```

someone is doing

```
$(".a").on('click',function () {alert('1')});
// ...and later
$(".a").on('click',function () {alert('2')});
```

Now , I want to find : *"which functions are executed when clicking the element"* ?

How can I do it in Jquery/Javascript?

*p.s. please ignore the anonymous functions here , I could also attach a regular named function .*

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/apageb/2/edit)

*(im using ( as jsbin shows , with 1.8.3 - the latest))*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223777/jquery-can-i-get-a-reference-to-the-bound-events-on-an-element

Comment: Be careful with that: since events bubble, the event's handler might not be the event's target.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Querying the list of event listeners registered for a given event type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157969/querying-the-list-of-event-listeners-registered-for-a-given-event-type)

Comment: @eliah it is not working. 9the solutions there).  http://jsbin.com/apageb/3/edit

Comment: **it is not duplicate since its   been removed in the latest version of jQuery**

Comment: @ToniToniChopper i didnt talk about the console. The answers on the duplicate doesnt work.( in jquery 1.8.3(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
console.log($._data( $(".a")[0], "events" ));
```

[Tested in 1.8.2](http://jsfiddle.net/c43tt/)

Comment: Also note that this method has been recommended against by the jQuery devs for anything more than debugging. http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/

Comment: Thanks=Thanks+1.( i guess it is better than grep hhhhhh)

Comment: @RoyiNamir http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQDtrD5xhHvIgBy7Xo4F57D-heg-p_8uteKtp4CmcBpXdok4DP3HE05YG5D

Comment: what is the $ symbol?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it with the current and older versions of jQuery, however it is internal and depreciated and will be going away soon.

```
console.log($(".a").data("events"));
```

Comment: Ah, it has already been removed in the latest version of jQuery. The last version it worked in was 1.7.2.