# Jquery: trigger one handler of the same event

Tags: jquery

I have multiple on change events.

```
$('#parent').change(function(){ console.log("first"); });
$('#parent').change(function(){ console.log("second"); });
```

It triggers both handlers when I trigger "change"

```
$('#parent').trigger('change')
```

OUTPUT:

```
"first"
"second"
```

What I want to do (pseudo code)

```
$('#parent').trigger('change:first')
```

or

```
$('#parent').trigger('<handler_id>')
```

OUTPUT

```
"first"
```

How do I do this? 
And, yes I need 2 handlers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What comes to my mind is that you could alternatively use event.stopImmediatePropagation() in the first handler if there is a clear condition when the second handler shouldn't fire, or fetch the element's handlers and just fire the first one of them manually (see [jQuery find events handlers registered with an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object)).

Comment: stopImmediatePropagation requires less code change in my case, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [namespaces](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) when you assign events.

```
$('#parent').bind('change.first',function(){ console.log("first"); });
$('#parent').bind('change.second',function(){ console.log("second"); });
```

This way you can trigger them with

```
('#parent').trigger('change.first');
```

or

```
('#parent').trigger('change.second');
```

---

But when you fire the event through normal user interaction (*and not manually triggering it*) it will fire both.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**namespaced events**](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events):

```
$('#parent').bind('change.a', function(){ console.log("first"); });
$('#parent').bind('change.b', function(){ console.log("second"); });

$('#parent').trigger('change.a');
```

The pattern is `event.namespace`. `$('#parent').trigger('change')` will still trigger both (so you are not loosing anything).