# jQuery/javascript - Wire up event handler only when its not already assigned

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm assigning an onclick handler to a checkbox. Sometimes javascript that does the binding of event runs more than once (on partial postbacks) and the handler gets assigned twice. How can I prevent the handler from being assigned multiple times?

Okay thanks for responses. I wrote something up to figure out if element has a hanlder:

```
$.fn.hasHandler = function(eventName, handler)
{
    var _hasHandler = false;

    if(handler != undefined && this.data("events") !== null && this.data("events") !== undefined)
    {
        $.each(this.data("events"), function(name, handlers)
        {
            if(name === eventName)      
            {
                $.each(handlers, function(index, value)
                {
                    if(value.handler === handler)
                    {
                        _hasHandler = true;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    return _hasHandler;
}
```

Comment: If you're looking at partial post backs, are you re-assigning the handler because the element has been recreated?

Comment: IMO you need to improve your structure a bit as assigning events in JS code which is rendered on partial postbacks isn't really a good idea. I would love to know your use-case why you can't pull the event code to applicaton wide javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" />
```

Your javascript might be:

```
var clickFound = false;
$.each($("#myCheck").data('events'), function(i, e) {
    if(i === 'click') {
        clickFound = true;
    }
});
if(!clickFound) {
    $("#myCheck").click(function() {
       // ...
    });
}
```

See more on testing for events bound via jQuery [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object).

Is there a reason, though, you can't use [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or the older [live](http://api.jquery.com/live) to allow your handler to be bound once and then to persist for all matched elements?

Comment: fyi for people who are reading this, i updated question with my final solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can unbind first.

$('#foo').unbind('click').bind('click', function(){...do stuff here...});

Comment: Although `unbind(eventName)` will unbind ALL click event handlers. If the function is stored in a variable, it can be unbound individually.

Comment: this could be a easier fix but that doesn't answer my original question. thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class to your checkbox when you add the click handler, and then later check for the existence of the class.

You could also [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind) the click handler before adding one as an alternative.

Or, probably the cleanest thing to do would be to prevent your code from running twice.