# jQuery bind event listener before another

Tags: jquery

Using the [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) plugin to open modal-style content containers, and trying to integrate with Google Analytics' Event Tracking to track when videos get opened.

Trouble is, when I

```
$('a.videoClickListener').click(function(event){
    console.log('here');
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Product Page', 'Video Open', '<?php echo $product->getNameWithManufacturer(); ?>']);
});
```

the event is never fired, as prettyPhoto stops the event from continuing (quite rightly, as otherwise the page would change if a hyperlink was clicked).

prettyPhoto does not seem to provide an 'open' callback function, but if it did I couldn't use it anyway, as the prettyPhoto listeners are set up somewhere in the layout (we use `rel="prettyPhoto"` every time we want to use prettyPhoto, and pass params through the URL, which is the prettyPhoto-recommended way of doing things).  I would also like to pass the product details to Analytics, ruling out a global video-opening listener across all prettyPhoto opening events.

How can I bind my listener *before* the prettyPhoto listener?  If it turns out I have to use `.unbind()`, then bind my listener, and then rebind prettyPhoto, how can I unbind a handler specified in a plugin?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ideally, you would be able to add *your* event binding *before* any others, so that it executes first.

Unfortunately, jQuery doesn't seem to include any such facility.

However, I've coded a [preBind method](https://gist.github.com/1046209), which seems to do the trick:

```
$.fn.preBind = function(type, data, fn) {
  this.bind(type, data, fn);

  var currentBindings = this.data('events')[type];
  var currentBindingsLastIndex = currentBindings.length - 1;

  var newBindings = [];

  newBindings.push(currentBindings[currentBindingsLastIndex]);

  $.each(currentBindings, function (index) {
    if (index < currentBindingsLastIndex)
      newBindings.push(this);
  });

  this.data('events')[type] = newBindings;

  return this;
};
```

Usage:

```
$('#button').bind('click', function() {
  console.log('world');
});

// 2nd apostrophe for the selector was missing
$('#button').preBind('click', function() {
  console.log('hello');
});

$('#button').click();

// Output:
//
// > "hello"
// > "world"
```

Comment: Try out following solution to get the events in newer and older jQuery versions: stackoverflow.com/a/26892146/655224

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'change' of undefined(…)

Answer (score 18):

I'm using Jonathan's preBind method, slightly modified, and it does the trick nicely.

```
$.fn.preBind = function (type, data, fn) {
    this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.bind(type, data, fn);

        var currentBindings = $this.data('events')[type];
        if ($.isArray(currentBindings)) {
            currentBindings.unshift(currentBindings.pop());
        }
    });
    return this;
};
```

Comment: +1: The code is an isofunctional optimization of jonathanconway's.

Comment: In newer versions of jQuery `$this.data('events')[type]` doesn't work. You must use `$._data(this, 'events')[type]`

Comment: @RichardRout Try out following solution to get the events in newer and older jQuery versions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26892146/655224

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'change' of undefined(…)

Answer (score 7):

Here is a variant of the solution using the more modern .On() approach.

```
// Same as .on() but moves the binding to the front of the queue.
$.fn.priorityOn = function (type, selector, data, fn) {
    this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        var types = type.split(" ");

        for (var t in types) {
            $this.on(types[t], selector, data, fn);

            var currentBindings = $._data(this, 'events')[types[t]];
            if ($.isArray(currentBindings)) {
                currentBindings.unshift(currentBindings.pop());
            }
        }


    });
    return this;
};
```

Usage is like

```
$(document).priorityOn("click blur change", ".some .selector input", function (e) {
    // Your code.
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Worked for me with older and newer `jQuery` versions:

```
/**
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/a/26892146/655224
 */
jQuery.fn.getEvents = function() {
    if (typeof(jQuery._data) == 'function') {
        return jQuery._data(this.get(0), 'events') || {};
    } else if (typeof(this.data) == 'function') { // jQuery version < 1.7.?
        return this.data('events') || {};
    }
    return {};
};

jQuery.fn.preBind = function(type, data, fn) {
    this.each(function () {
        var $this = jQuery(this);

        $this.bind(type, data, fn);

        var currentBindings = $this.getEvents()[type];
        if (jQuery.isArray(currentBindings)) {
            currentBindings.unshift(currentBindings.pop());
        }
    });
    return this;
};
```

But beware, this functions can only return/prebind that events that was set with jQuery itself.

Special thanks to @jonathanconway and @Patrick...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly modified version of braks answer that also supports namespaces and type as plain object:

```
$.fn.prioOn = function(type, selector, data, fn, /*INTERNAL*/ one) {
    // Types can be a map of types/handlers
    if (typeof types === 'object') {
        // ( types-Object, selector, data )
        if (typeof selector !== 'string') {
            // ( types-Object, data )
            data = data || selector;
            selector = undefined;
        }
        for (type in types) {
            if (!types.hasOwnProperty(type)) continue;
            this.prioOn(type, selector, data, types[type], one);
        }
        return this;
    }
    this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        var types = type.split(' ');

        for (var t in types) {
            if (!types.hasOwnProperty(t)) continue;
            $this.on(types[t], selector, data, fn, one);

            var currentBindings = $._data(this, 'events')[types[t].split('.')[0]];
            if ($.isArray(currentBindings)) {
                currentBindings.unshift(currentBindings.pop());
            }
        }
    });
    return this;
};
```

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me, jQuery v3.6.1

Answer (score 1):

Had to change one line in the above code to make it work:

```
    var currentBindings = $this.data('events',type); // var currentBindings = $this.data('events')[type];
```

This could be because I am using jquery 2.0.3

Comment: In 1.8.3 I had to use the following: 
```$._data(this, "events")[type];```. Note 'this' is the actual html element and not a jQuery object.

Answer (score -1):

if you use unbind() then even the bindings made by plugins will be unbinded.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  How would I go about selecting an event to unbind?  Are they named somehow?  In prettyPhoto the listener is bound as an anonymous function.

Comment: how prettyphoto is stopping the event? If both you and plugin are listening to some type of event on the same item there is no way that the plugin can stop firing you bind. Listen to the same type of event the plugin listens to and also listen exactly on the same element.

Comment: Thanks once again.  It seems to be working now...  I must have made another mistake somewhere (possibly not encoding the product name when passing to javascript from PHP).