# jQuery click() firing after Bootstrap click, causing conflicts

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have Bootstrap 3.3.5 (CSS and JS) with jQuery 1.11.0 installed on a page ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbwebtech/sk4suevu/)) with a `btn-group` series of checkboxes.  I am trying to bind a jQuery click event to all labels (the buttons) that will count checked inputs and show a validation message if zero are selected.

Additionally, I would like to remove `btn-default` and add `btn-primary` for the selected button, so it will stand out in the UI more.  This would net having both `btn-primary` and `active` classes applied at the same time.  However it seems my jQuery `click()` is firing before the bootstrap click is firing, so my function returns inaccurate data (as far as the user is concerned).

How can I make the jQuery `click()` event fire after the bootstrap event(s) have finished?

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbwebtech/sk4suevu/), and thanks!

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2 control-label-colon-after" for="Selected_Days">Selected Days</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons" id="dayOfWeekGroup">
                <label class="btn btn-default pcs-weekday" id="lblDayOfWeek_Monday">
                    <input autocomplete="off" id="DayOfWeek_Monday" name="DayOfWeek_Monday" type="checkbox" value="Monday"> Mon
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default pcs-weekday" id="lblDayOfWeek_Tuesday">
                    <input autocomplete="off" id="DayOfWeek_Tuesday" name="DayOfWeek_Tuesday" type="checkbox" value="Tuesday"> Tue
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default pcs-weekday" id="lblDayOfWeek_Wednesday">
                    <input autocomplete="off" id="DayOfWeek_Wednesday" name="DayOfWeek_Wednesday" type="checkbox" value="Wednesday"> Wed
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default pcs-weekday" id="lblDayOfWeek_Thursday">
                    <input autocomplete="off" id="DayOfWeek_Thursday" name="DayOfWeek_Thursday" type="checkbox" value="Thursday"> Thu
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default pcs-weekday" id="lblDayOfWeek_Friday">
                    <input autocomplete="off" id="DayOfWeek_Friday" name="DayOfWeek_Friday" type="checkbox" value="Friday"> Fri
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default pcs-weekend" id="lblDayOfWeek_Saturday">
                    <input autocomplete="off" id="DayOfWeek_Saturday" name="DayOfWeek_Saturday" type="checkbox" value="Saturday"> Sat
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default pcs-weekend" id="lblDayOfWeek_Sunday">
                    <input autocomplete="off" id="DayOfWeek_Sunday" name="DayOfWeek_Sunday" type="checkbox" value="Sunday"> Sun
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <span id="dayOfWeekGroupValidationErr" class="field-validation-valid text-danger" style="display: none;">At least one day of the week is required to create a schedule block</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#dayOfWeekGroup label').click(function() {

    // add primary class if button selected, or remove if deselected
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-primary');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
    }

    // count how many buttons are selected, and show a validation error if zero
    if ($('#dayOfWeekGroup').find('input:checked').length > 0) { 
        $('#dayOfWeekGroupValidationErr').hide();
        return true;
    }
    $('#dayOfWeekGroupValidationErr').show();
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is where you are checking the checkboxes values, because a click event is fired before the checkbox value changes. To solve the issue you can use the change event instead.

```
$('#dayOfWeekGroup label').change(function() { ... }
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sk4suevu/3/

Comment: exactly what I was looking for!  Couldn't see the trees through the forest.  Thank you @caeth!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this:

```
$('#dayOfWeekGroup input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    var label = $(this).closest("label");

     // add primary class if button selected, or remove if deselected
    if ($(label).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-primary');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
    }

    // count how many buttons are selected, and show a validation error if zero
    if ($("#dayOfWeekGroup").find(".active").length > 0) {
        $('#dayOfWeekGroupValidationErr').hide();
        return true;
    }
    $('#dayOfWeekGroupValidationErr').show();
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the bootstrap js (script src) after your js code and not before, like this

```
<script>
    ... your code
</script>
<script src="/route/to/bootstrap.js">
```

also you can see this answer [jQuery bind event listener before another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029251/jquery-bind-event-listener-before-another) for a pre-bind solution