# Can't get this dropped down menu to work JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

On the code I am working below, in the tab called issues, when you hover over it a subsequent menu drops down. It disappears when you leave the tab which is good. However, I would like the new sub-menu to stay when hovering over it.

.issues is the sub-menu and I want to add class of active when hovering over it and remove it when not. This part seems to work well. For the mouseout part of the function, I want to check if the sub-menu has class active, if it does I want the sub-menu to remain which is achieved with this part of the if statement !$('.issues').hasClass('active'). It does not seem to work however.

What I think happens is that when the mouseover event happens, the call stack conducts this check first if ($(this).next().prop('nodeName') == 'UL' && !$('.issues').hasClass('active')) before adding the class of active to the sub-menu.

How can I make it so that the class is added first before the mouseout event fires?

PS is this a possible solution? [jQuery bind event listener before another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029251/jquery-bind-event-listener-before-anotheremphasized) text

```js
$('.issues').hover(function () {
        $('.issues').addClass('active');
    }, function () {
        $('.issues').removeClass('active');
    });

    $('nav > ul > li').hover(function () {
        if ($(this).next().prop('nodeName') == 'UL') {
            $(this).next().slideDown('slow');
        }}, function () {
            // console.log($(this).next().prop('nodeName') == 'UL' &&
            //  !$('.issues').hasClass('active'));
            if ($(this).next().prop('nodeName') == 'UL' &&
                !$('.issues').hasClass('active')) {
                $('.issues').slideUp('up');
                }}
    );
```

```css
.issues {
    display: none;
    position: static;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
<ul>
                <li><a>Issues</a></li>
                <ul class="issues">
                    <li><a>X</a></li>
                    <li><a>Y</a></li>
                    <li><a>Z</a></li>
                </ul>
                <li><a>Press Releases</a></li>
                <li><a>Donate</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your issue correctly this should solve here is the breakdown:

- I added a hover listener for both the "Issues" tab and the submenu.
- Used setTimeout to introduce a short delay before hiding the submenu.
- If the mouse returns to either area during this delay, the submenu won't hide.
- This ensures smooth transitions without unexpected hide/show actions.

```js
let timeout;

$('nav > ul > li, .issues').on('mouseenter', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout); 
    $('.issues').slideDown('slow'); 
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.issues').slideUp('slow');
    }, 300);
});

$('.issues').on('mouseenter', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout); 
})
```

```css
.issues {
    display: none;
    position: static;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
<ul>
                <li><a>Issues</a></li>
                <ul class="issues">
                    <li><a>X</a></li>
                    <li><a>Y</a></li>
                    <li><a>Z</a></li>
                </ul>
                <li><a>Press Releases</a></li>
                <li><a>Donate</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Aye this is what I was looking to accomplish. Thanks for the help.