# How to check if a click event has been assigned to a button or not - JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am `bind`ing a click event in jquery by:

```
$('#myButton').bind('click',  onButtonClicked);
```

It works great the first time, but then the view gets rerendered and although I am rebinding the event, it doesn't seem to be working.

I am debugging via firebug and how do I know using JQuery that the `click` event has been assigned to this button? It doesn't appear to get translated to a `onClick` event in the HTML.

**EDIT:**

I think the issue appears to be because I am doing something like this:

```
$("#myDiv").html("<input type='button' id='myButton'/>");
$('#myButton').bind('click',  onButtonClicked);
```

Is this valid? The `$("#myButton").data("events")` appears to have a click event assigned to it, but it does nothing when I click the button.

Comment: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10589

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start [jQuery find events handlers registered with an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object)

```
$('#myButton').data('events');
```

You can then iterate over the returned object to see what events are bound.

```
$.each($("#myButton").data("events"), function(i, e) {
    alert(i);
});
```

Comment: Where and what is onButtonClicked?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know wether I understand you but here is my try:

You should add it to the document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myButton').bind('click',  onButtonClicked);
});
```

If you are adding element later dynamically you can use jQuery's `live()` or even better `delegate()`

http://api.jquery.com/live/

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

delegate would be the better option performance wise

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to html tab, select your node and then click on the green link (the one with "object{events.......}") and then you can see all events attached to the node

[image]

Otherwise you can use [visual event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) that creates an overlay that shows all events on your page. It's very useful.