# Test for events registered to a given object with .live()

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I've tried the answer suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2518421/409279), which follows with nearly all answers to similar/duplicate questions. Checking `.data('events')` simply isn't working, returning `undefined` for objects I had previously (*immediately at that*) registered an event to.

Now, the caveat is that I'm actually registering said events with `.live()`, rather than `.bind()` or the alias methods.

---

I just read (*previous to my even posting the question*) the following from jQuery on `.live()`:

> The `.live()` method is able to affect elements that have not yet been added to the DOM through the use of event delegation: a handler bound to an ancestor element is responsible for events that are triggered on its descendants. **The handler passed to `.live()` is never bound to an element; instead, `.live()` binds a special handler to the root of the DOM tree**. In the example above, when the new element is clicked...

Given this information, what would I do (*if possible at all*) to check whether an event is "registered" to a given object with `.live()`? With this new-found information, I'm guessing it'll start with the `window` or `document` object...

---

**Idea update:** If there is a way to tap into the DOM monitoring capabilities of `.live()`, perhaps I could simply re-bind events via `.bind()` whenever a change occurs (*identically to that of `.live()`, with however, support for the `.data('events')` inspection as the events are directly bound.*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track...you can find the handlers bound by calls to `live()` in the document's data object: `$.data(document, "events").live`

Something like this should be a good starting point to accomplish what you want:

```
function isRegisteredByLive(selector, eventType)
{
    var isRegistered = false;

    // iterate through all "live"  event handlers and check whether the
    // handler applies to the specified selector and event type
    $.each($.data(document, "events").live, function(idx, obj) {
        if (obj.selector === selector && obj.origType === eventType)
        {
            isRegistered = true;
            return false; // break
        } 
    });

    return isRegistered;
}

$('a').live('click', function() { alert('test'); });

isRegisteredByLive('a', 'click'); // returns true
```

You could also do something like this to identify all live handlers bound to a specific DOM element:

```
function getLiveEvents(el)
{
    $.each($.data(document, "events").live, function(idx, obj) {
        if ($(el).closest(obj.selector).length > 0)
        {
            console.log(obj.handler);
        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks @RocccoC5 - Worked like a charm, I just needed to add an offset to `obj` in the first solution (*`obj[0].selector` since it returns a single-element array*)

Comment: @Bracketworks - Glad to hear it. Not sure about why you would need to specify an index on `obj`, though.  The call to `each()` should be iterating through each of the objects in the `$.data(document, "events").live` array and passing to the function the index of the object as the `idx` param, and the actual object as the `obj` param.  Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Xu3Yn/1/

Answer (score 1):

I recently updated jQuery to the latest (1.7.1) and I realized that I cannot use

```
var liveEvents = $.data(document, "events").live;
```

because live is not there anymore. Instead you check for click, change, etc. Here is the updated version of the code that I posted on SO before (with older jQuery versions use the other one posted on this page):

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.eventRegistered = function (eventName, includeLiveEvents) {
        if (includeLiveEvents != true)
            includeLiveEvents = false;

        if (this == null || this.length == 0)
            return false;

        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
            var events = $(this[0]).data("events");

            if (events == null)
                continue;

            if (events[eventName] != null)
                return true;
        }

        if (includeLiveEvents) {
            return this.eventRegisteredLive(eventName);
        }

        return false;
    };
})(jQuery);

(function ($) {
    $.fn.eventRegisteredLive = function (eventName) {
        var liveEvents = $.data(document, "events")[eventName];

        if (!liveEvents)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < liveEvents.length; ++i) {
            if (liveEvents[i].selector == this.selector)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a jQuery function that checks if events for an element is registered (on element and live if necessary)

Code:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.eventRegistered = function (eventName, includeLiveEvents) {
        if (includeLiveEvents != true)
            includeLiveEvents = false;

        if (this == null || this.length == 0)
            return false;

        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
            var events = $(this[0]).data("events");

            if (events == null)
                continue;

            if (events[eventName] != null)
                return true;
        }

        if (includeLiveEvents) {
            var liveEvents = $.data(document, "events").live;

            for (var i = 0; i < liveEvents.length; ++i) {
                if (liveEvents[i].selector == this.selector && liveEvents[i].origType == eventName)
                    return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Examplary usage:
    var isRegistered = $('.className').eventRegistered("click"); // will return true if click is registeren on at least one element that has a class className

```
var isRegistered = $('.className').eventRegistered("change", true); // will return true if change is registered on at least one element that has a class className or using live function
```

Be careful. This function breaks the chain, so you cannot use it like:

```
$('.className').eventRegistered("change").change(function() {
    // ...
});
```