# how to retrieve onlick events added with click()

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery find events handlers registered with an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object)

How can you retrieve all onlick methods added with click()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will return an array of objects:

```
$(foo).data("events").click
```

Access the `handler` member to get the function:

```
$(foo).data("events").click[0].handler
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q7hdz/

---

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

> jQuery itself uses the .data() method to save information under the names 'events' and 'handle'...

So Alnitak's warning below may apply.

Comment: Danger Will Robinson!  These are jQuery internals and could change.