# How to find where jquery event handlers are assigned?

Tags: jquery

For some reason I have an additional change handler on a number input.  I can't for the life of me figure out where it is coming from.  Can anyone point me in the direction of how I can track down this rouge event handler assignment?  In chrome dev tools if I inspect the element and look at the event handlers area it just points to (1) jquery and (2) undefined.

[image]

Comment: I'm using  a standard $("#id").bind("change", handler) call.  But even if I comment out the handler I'm trying to use, the above handler is still present.  I even tried putting in a call to unbind.  No dice.  I just wasn't sure if there was a way to track through the call stack or something that would lead me to where the assignment is being added.

Comment: undefined usually means that it's inline javascript, not an external file.

Comment: Is there an inline `onchange=` attribute?

Comment: maybe this will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object

Answer (score 1):

If the other handler is undesired, you can always use `unbind` :

```
$("#id").unbind('change').bind("change", handler);
```

Of course, you'll have to take into consideratin every possible case, so a complete solutin would be :

```
$("#id")
    .off('change')
    .die('change')
    .unbind('change')
    .on("change", handler);
```

Answer (score 1):

All of events binded by jquery are in `$( target ).data( 'events' )`;
That represents object with keys as name of event contains array of functions.

For example try this in console on stackoverflow directly:
    `$('a').data('events').click[0].handler`;

To list each of event type calbacks assigned by jquery  object try:

```
$.each( $( youSelector ).data('events'), function(v,k){
   console.log( v +":");
   $(this).each( function(){
     console.log( this.handler );
   });
   console.log("------------------");
});
```

Way to find  out  from which file they came is search from  piece of handler code  in console on search input in resources tab :)

Answer (score 0):

These answers weren't quite what I was looking for but I was able to find out where the handlers were coming from.  I'm using webshims and a jquery tool called overlay.  Apparently the overlay executes the code in the script tag when the page is rendered and again when the overlay is actually applied.