# Javascript how to find the source a scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, scroll

I have this funny bug that occurs and I am at a loss as to how to debug it.  Every time a page loads on my site a scroll event fires.  The page doesn't visibly move, and i certainly am not triggering the scrolling via the mouse or keyboard.  I know that scroll event is firing because i put a line of code that reads

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function (e) {console.log(e)});
```

Sure enough on every page i get a little "jQuery.Event" message in my console's log.  When i break point it my call stack ends at jQuery.even.dispatch.apply(eventHandle.elem, arguments), which doesn't give me a ton to work with.

Here's the question.  How do I find out what is triggering this scroll event?  Is there an attribute in the jquery event object that will tell me if the scroll was user triggered or triggered by a script?  In this situation what would you do to figure this out?

Comment: You could try setting breakpoints in your browser and try to narrow down the source manually.

Comment: read the line, "When i break point it my call stack ends at jQuery.even.dispatch.apply(eventHandle.elem, arguments), which doesn't give me a ton to work with."

Comment: Could this possibly be a stack overflow issue? I've seen event handling in jQuery do this before... how long is the call stack?

Comment: there are three functions on the stack :-/

Comment: what do you have in `e.target` and `e.which` ??

Comment: target is htmldocument, and which is undefined

Comment: I don't know if this could shed any light, but the project im working on where this issue reared it's head was a responsive redesign.  Also the website adds a lot of content dynamically after page load via jquery.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I'm also at a loss of how to find what triggers the scroll event. My app is also a jquery-based responsive website. Did you find a way in the meantime?

Comment: @aamiri did you find any solution to this? I'm having the same problem right now though in an Android Cordova app that isn't using jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, it looks like jQuery hides all event binding data within a hidden attribute. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518441/1558430) describes ways that lets you find out at least what is being run -- it is still your responsibility to find out where the handlers are in which file.

In the case where `scroll` events are involved:

```
var scrollHandlers = jQuery._data(window, 'events')['scroll'];
for (var i = 0; i < scrollHandlers.length; i++) {
    console.error(scrollHandlers[i].handler);  // or console.debug, whatever proves they exist
}
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question because his scroll is probably being triggered in an onload or somesuch and this only finds scroll handlers. But +1 anyway because `jQuery._data(window, 'events')` was a great thing to learn.