# How to know which handler is attached to an element in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am debugging this code. I would like to know how to see which handler is attached to `img`.

```
img.unbind('error').bind('error', function() {
    img.unbind('error').attr('src', 'img/cover-empty.png');
});
```

I would like print the result using `console.log()`

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object) could help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you have not mentioned the id or class for img

```
 $.each($("<img selector>").data("events"), function(e, event) {
   $.each(event, function(a, obj) {
    console.log(obj.handler);
 });
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/968jj/890/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
 var events = $(img).data("events");

 console.log(events); // -> Object { error=[1] }
```

See a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RienNeVaPlus/2kvqr/)