# Get click handler from element in JQuery

Tags: events, event-handling, jquery

How can I get a reference to the click handler of an element in JQuery?

Here is what I am trying to do:

Store the click handler,
Change the click handler for the next click,
Restore the original click handler

```
var originalClick = $(settings.currentTarget).click;
$(settings.currentTarget).off("click");

$(settings.currentTarget).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    settings.model.modal.close();

    $(settings.currentTarget).off("click");
    $(settings.currentTarget).click(originalClick);
});
```

The above code works the first time, however, when I click on the element again it fails:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'on'
```

**Update:**

I now realize that this is a really bad design that I am trying to do.  I have resolved this issue by maintaining a visibility boolean in my viewmodel, if it is true, don't re-open the modal.

Comment: `$(settings.currentTarget).click` is the function you are binding the event handler with. It is not the event handler itself. How was the original event handler bound? With jQuery or any other way?

Comment: @FelixKling the original click handler was bound using knockout.

Comment: This might be able to help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object

Comment: So you used a `click` binding? I don't know how it works internally but I assume knockout is using `addEventListener`. There is no way to get a reference to handlers bound this way.

Comment: I think you're getting that message because you're calling  `$(settings.currentTarget).off("click");` again during the click and never called .On first. It looks like it was already .off as you have at the top.

Comment: @Pjack .off should be removing the click handler on line 4, then I should be adding a new click handler using the original function.

Comment: @FelixKling is there anyway to accomplish what I am trying to do if knockout uses addEventListener?

Answer (score 7):

`$(...).click` is the jQuery `click()` method, not your event handler.

You can use an [undocumented internal API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518441/34397) to get the list of event handlers:

```
jQuery._data( elem, "events" );
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try it this way?

```
  var originalClick = $(settings.currentTarget).click;
    $(settings.currentTarget).off("click");

    $(settings.currentTarget).on("click",function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        settings.model.modal.close();

        $(settings.currentTarget).off("click");
        $(settings.currentTarget).click(originalClick);
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately that gives me the same thing.  I think that what I need to do is get this new click handler to execute before the original one and stopPropagation, just not sure how to do that.

Comment: I don't think you're using .Off() correctly. Why are you trying to unbind something that you haven't bound yet? From the jQuery documentation `The off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on().` The first time you call it, you never attached it with .on() first. You might be mixing things.

Comment: Can you give more info on what you're trying to do? What is `settings.currentTarget`? Also I noticed you said you were using knockout.js. Any reason this part can't be done with jQuery?

Comment: Using `var originalClick = $(settings.currentTarget).click;` doesn't make sense. `jQuery.fn.click` is a jQuery method, not an event handler. You cannot bind it as event handler.

Comment: @FelixKling  I know, that is what I told him. I think he used knockout or something to bind initially.