# Retrieve onclick listeners of an <a> tag and remove to make it 'disabled'

Tags: javascript, jquery

> First of all, this problem originates from the fact the `HTML` anchor cannot be set to `disabled`.

I have a lot of anchors (the `<a>` tag) in my site that serves as button, lists,  menu items, etc. They cannot be disabled but under some circumstances, I need to disable them. To make them disabled I'm planning to do the following:

1. Add class to the specific anchor that will make them grey-ed out and *"unclickable"*.
2. Temporarily remove all it `onclick` events and reattach it after. I plan to do this by:

   1. Retrieving all the `onclick` handlers and saving it to an `Array` of `functions()` to be retrieved later, in case you want to enable it again later. *(I don't know how to do this yet!)*
   2. Then remove all the `onclick` listeners

**I'm asking a way to retrieve only handlers for onclick events**, but all I see is about retrieving all types of attached events.

---

**EDIT :** Guys, I appreciate the answers on how to disable anchors... but *[you know, ]* that is not my question. Some of the solutions are not possible on my scenario (too complicated to discuss here), and the solution above is currently the easiest thing that I can do. What I really want to know is how to perform something like this:

```
var handlers = []
handlers = $("#anchor").getClickEvents()
```

Comment: Instead you could remove the src attribute, copying the value into a data-src attribute for example, and then resetting it when you want to re-enable it.

Comment: @IanDevlin Thanks, that could work... though the anchors we're talking here are bunch of `href="#"`...

Comment: ah ok, this is something different. You could set something like data-disabled on the a elements that you want to disable, and then within their click handlers, return false for elements that have that attribute. It just might be simpler.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200590/get-click-handler-from-element-in-jquery

Comment: I don't understand why do you want to do this.. You can simply disable the click event for certain links, without having to save the links handlers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a:not(.disabled)', function(){
    console.log($(this).text() + ' was clicked');
}).on('click', 'a.disabled', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('a').trigger('click');
$('a.disabled').removeClass('disabled');
$('a').trigger('click');
```

Assign the `.on` event to the anchors parent so any changes will be taken in consideration.

The HTML in the demo:

```
<a href="#">1</a>
<a href="#">2</a>
<a href="#">3</a>
<a href="#" class="disabled">4</a>
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eaLf7csy/)

Answer (score 2):

If you return false on onClick event then it will cancel the event. If you return true, it will proceed normally. If you are using jQuery you can use following snippet:

jQuery:

```
$('a.something').click(function (e) {
      //do nothing  
      e.preventDefault();
});
```

javascript:

```
function clickLink(){
   if(condition)
             return false;
}
```