# Turning all events .off() and .on() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm looking at using `.off()` and `.on()` to turn event handlers off and on in jQuery.

I can turn the **all attached** event handlers **off** perfectly by using:

```
$('.eventone').off();
```

or as a multiple selector:

```
$('.eventone, .eventtwo, .eventthree').off();
```

However, I'm not getting **all (or even any)** event handlers to turn back **on**. I'm using this:

```
$('.eventone, .eventtwo, .eventthree').on();
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Do I actually have to declare **every event** that's associated with the **class** in order to turn it back on?

Comment: Yes. `.off()` doesn't disable events, it removes them completely.

Comment: @PatrickEvans what do you mean a global variable? From what I gather, right now using `.off()` is out of the question, am I right?

Comment: If you're really into this behavior, you can save an array connecting events and their elements, the use .off(), and afterwards call a function that runs on your array and returns the events. This might be useful: [jQuery find events handlers registered with an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object)

Comment: @Juhana also, thanks for that little bite of info -- made me realize I was totally climbing up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `.off` basically removes the events so you will have redeclare them. you are better off having a global variable so your event handlers can check to see if it set to off or on and if off just return. And just change the variable to off or on, true or false or whatever suits you

```
var eventsOn = false;
function myFunc() {
   if(!eventsOn) return;

   //Code to run here.
}

//Somewhere else set your events and turn eventsOn to true
jQuery("#mydiv").on("click",myFunc);
eventsOn = true;
```

Comment: AHH. I get what you mean now. Thanks!

Comment: I don't recommend multiline braceless IFs. If you want to go braceless, remove the line break. I you can't fit into one line, add braces. The reason is that these tend to break when copy-pasting stuff.

Comment: @JanDvorak what you mean would be to do it like this: `function myFunc() {if(!eventsOn){return;}}`, right?

Comment: @Reno Yeo, he just means having the if look like this, `if(!eventsOn) return;` on one line