# Is there a way to tell programmatically if clicking an element will have any effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given an element, is there any way to tell with Javascript/jQuery whether there are any click events on that element?

I mean ANY click events. If clicking it would cause ANY code to execute, I want to know about it.

Is this possible?

It must be, if Firebug and Chrome Dev Tools can see all the event listeners tied to an object...

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: Still need to explain you answer more in detail. It is not understandable yet.

Comment: Possible tooltips, proper use of Title tags?..

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object

Comment: highlight it on hover

Comment: @user814064: how about event delegation?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/A7Pcq/ - for everyone who thinks it's possible - do that with this code.

Comment: @Aerovistae: still, **why** do you need that? Are you sure it's not XY-problem?

Comment: A similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node

Comment: @zerkms what? what is an xy-problem? and because I want to find all clickable elements...that's why.

Comment: @Aerovistae: **why** do you need to find them? What **original** issue are you trying to solve with this terrible solution?

Comment: Haha...I see this is getting to you...I am sorry...I don't want to give away the game but trust me that you're not seeing the big picture here. Essentially, I'm building a tool that provides an alternate means of interacting with a page..and so I need to be aware of all interactive parts of the page. Just finding <a> tags would not suffice for pages such as gmail where everything is a span or a div.

Comment: @Aerovistae: sure we don't see the whole picture - because you didn't explain it. The thing is - you're solving your task in an incorrect and error prone way (see how I provided a case for every answer to fail). But anyway, you think it's fine - great and good luck :-)

Comment: See edit to that comment for some details.

Comment: @Aerovistae: well, it's impossible to get. Delegation is what used widely and what you won't be able to catch with any of provided solutions (well, possible if you traverse all the nodes up the tree and check)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36377/discussion-between-aerovistae-and-zerkms)

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of events attached to particular element jquery uses

```
​$._data( $("#yourelement")[0], "events" );
```

Comment: @zerkms Replace your fiddle code with the correct one $('div').on('click', 'span', function() {
    alert('handler');
});
console.log($._data( $("#hello")[0], "events" )); and your HTML as <div id="hello">
    <span>click me</span>
</div> Im able to view the results in console

Comment: the click handler is delegated to `span`, not to `div`. So your change is not correct. Put `id="hello"` to `span` and see it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

There is a script called [VisualEvent](https://github.com/DataTables/VisualEvent) that does just the work you want. You can look at its code and see what goes on there.

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/jvcDV/

HTML:

```
<a id="p1">I am link 1</a>
<a onclick="javascript:alert('hi');">I am link 2</a>
<a>I am link 3</a>
<a>I am link 4</a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Add inline event to a link element
    document.getElementById('p1').onclick = function() { alert('hi'); };
    $('a').each(function()
    {
        if(this.onclick == null)
        {
            alert("Link " + this.innerText + " does not have a onclick event");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Link " + this.innerText + " does have a onclick event");
        }
    });             
});
```