# Stop JS-event propagation on table row click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following HTML-table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Row 1
    </td>
    <td>
      <!-- Hidden JSF-button -->
      <button class="hide" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When I click on a `tr`, I trigger a click on the hidden button with JS:

```
$('table tr').on('click', function(e) {
  var $button = $(this).find('button');  
  console.log('trigger click on', $button);
  
  $button.trigger('click');
});
```

The click event propagates up, and will cause a never ending loop (can be seen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kDxHy)

After some searching on Stack Overflow, it is clear that the solution is to call `event.stopPropagation`,
like this (can be seen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BnlfA):

```
$('table tr').on('click', function(e) {
  var $button = $(this).find('button');
  
  // Prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.
  $button
    .off('click')
    .on('click', function(e) {
      console.log('click');
      e.stopPropagation();
    
    return true;
  });
  
  console.log('trigger click on', $button);
  
  $button.trigger('click');
});
```

The solution above works. But it feels like a hack, and I don't like it.

Do I have to register a click handler on the on the `$button` just to call `event.stopPropagation`? Are there any better way(s) of preventing the click event from bubbling?

Comment: why do you need to trigger click on that hidden button ?

Comment: The button is actually a hidden JSF-button (http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-button-and-commandbutton-example/). When a user clicks on a row in the table I trigger a click on the button, that calls the backing controller (server side) to set a value.

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't know MVC is involved. I'm not sure if this could help, but when you trigger event automaticaly, what's the event.target ? If it's button, that you could filter it and stopPropagation in tr event handler probably ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better overall solution would be not to trigger the `click` event at all but simply have a separate function that you can call and that encapsulates the event handler logic.

```
function doSomething(someArg) {
    //do something
}

$('button').click(function () {
    doSomething(/*pass whatever you want*/);
});

$('table tr').on('click', function () {
    doSomething(/*pass whatever you want*/);
});
```

Please note that `doSomething` doesn't have an event handler signature such as `(e)`. That's generally a good practice to pass just what's needed to the function to do it's own work, not the whole event object. That will simplify the implementation of `doSomething` and decouple it completely from the event object.

EDIT:

> Sorry, but I need to manually trigger the button click when the user
> clicks on a tr. Please see my comment to @magyar1984 question.

In this case you probably found the best solution already, which is to attach an event listener on the button and call `stopPropagation`. You could also look into getting all click event handlers by using the `events` data on the element, but beware that you would then be relying on jQuery internals so the code could break in future releases.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object) to know how to retrieve the event handlers.

Comment: Sorry, but I need to manually trigger the button click when the user clicks on a tr. Please see my comment to @magyar1984 question.

Comment: Thanks, yes I assume that the solution must be to manually prevent the event from bubbling. I made a plugin that could be used as a shortcut to prevent bubbling. http://nekman.se/prevent-jquery-event-from-bubbling/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to only register the button click once by updating your codepen to the following:

```
var handleClick = function(e) {
  var $button = $(this).find('button');  
  console.log('trigger click on', $button);

  $button.trigger('click');
};
$('button.hide').on('click',function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$(function() {
    $('table tr')
    .on('click', handleClick);
});
```

But the general idea is to declare an onClick event on the button and stop the propagation there.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying buttons behaviour, expecially in frameworks, can cause some unexpected issues. You could add a flag to the row and use it to check if the button should be clicked. But you have to know how many click are automatically generated and should be omitted.

```
var handleClick = function(e) {
  var $button = $(this).find('button');  
  console.log('triggerring click on...', $button);
  if (this.clicked !== true) {
    console.log('and clicked!')
    this.clicked = true;
    $button.trigger('click');
  } else
    this.clicked = false;
};
```

Here's the code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dJroL