# Remove all event handlers from an html5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am Building an HTML5 canvas javascript application. In that i am using many 'mousemouse','mousedown' event handlers each on different times. Can i remove all event handlers attached to the canvas only specifying the event 'mousemove' (with out specifying its call back function).

Comment: something like [`.on()/.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) ?

Comment: I assume that "mousemouse" means "mouseup" correct ?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) or [jQuery.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Answer (score 2):

You would use the [unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to remove an event like this:

```
$("selector").unbind("click");
```

Another method is [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
$( "p" ).off( "click", "**" );
```

This will remove all delegated click handlers from all paragraphs:

Answer (score 1):

Pure Javascript:

```
var canvas = ...;
canvas.removeEventListener('eventIDontWantAnymore', arguments.callee, false);
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tylerpachal/yL3n2/)**

Comment: I think he wants to remove all events without specifying its names