# Get the computed events from an HTML object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get the computed click events from an HTML object in JavaScript. I need to call the functions that execute when I click an HTML object. 
Something like the following but getting the function calls directly

```
$("#htmlobject").click();
```

Comment: please explain in more detail...how are these events being bound to element? Show more code

Comment: I don´t know, that´s why i want to know how to get them.

Comment: that's not enough detail to work from. WHat do you mean by `get them`? What you are asking is not trivial without details, and your full expectations.

Comment: Sorry I have a page not made for me and I need to run the functions called when I click an Object

Comment: really not clear what you are asking. Please provide a demo in jsfiddle.net that outlines issue.

Comment: <a id="a1">actions not made by  me</a>
I want to know what executes when that element is clicked

Comment: unless it has `onclick` inline...not much you can do with it. You still haven't properly explained objectives and expectations

Comment: it doesn´t have onclick inline, but it does call something, and I did not make the page

Comment: I am not sure but maybe this q&a can solve your problems.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is fairly poorly written to explain what you're looking for.

I'm guessing its this: "There are event handlers that 'someone' has put on an element, I would like to know what they are, and optionally be able to trigger them manually".  That said, the answer is "no, unless you bound the event callback its not yours to mess around with".

Other Reasons/Stuffs:

1. You can't be sure if all the events were added using jQuery, even if they were newer versions of jQuery store the events in a non externally accessible way.
2. You can't be sure if the event is on a child that bubbles, or on a parent that this will bubble to, etc... this would insanely complicate things.
3. Elements do have a bunch of attributes you can access for read and write like "onclick" but this only returns anything if it was defined that way in the element, it does not return things added via .addEventListener or via frameworks.
4. jQuery often abstracts things and adds them higher up, especially when done with live/on.. it will often actually subscribe to the parent element and let the events bubble up, then kinda "re-working" them so they appear to have been thrown by the "target"

Really though, even though you didn't write the page, if you have access to its source you can see what is being bound and where, you can see if they are using named callbacks or anonymous callbacks.

If the page is visible in the browser you can find it all, and as such I wonder what you mean by "I didn't make the page"

Answer (score 0):

Also these documentations can be useful:
http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#data-events-
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/#jQuery-data-element-key