# How to detect all events added on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jQuery and such kind of **js** frameworks. Till now I used to do like this

```
<div onclick="function()"></div>
```

But in jQuery we get the element and add the event there. How can I detect all events added on a div?

I have a div whose height is set to the remaining height. Then I cant find appropriate **css** for that. I strongly believe that it has been done from javascript. I cant find relavant code any where. I dont know how to debug this.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: try changing some option by inspect that element sometime element inherit some behavior or if it shows inline height it may be from js

Comment: You can change the `height` of that `div` irrelevant of what js did , unless and until you have any selector for that div

Comment: Why not just debug using Firebug for firefox. Its a handy debugging tool

Comment: try this http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event

Comment: don't believe,`Inspect`. Most modern browsers have inbuilt dom debugging and inspecting tools. Try chrome's or FF's 'Inspect Element'. Because, even if you detect all the events subscribed on a div, what's the point, how would you evaluate which one's doing what?

Comment: It was not done via java script. The element is positioned absolute, then they added these properties `top: 45px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px;` That is how the div occupied entire available height. I never knew this trick/solution.

Comment: As above use a debugger such as firebug and find the "break on next" feature. http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/firebug-15-break-on-next/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question you can use:

`jQuery._data( elem, "events" );`

This will become an object of all events attached to the selected element.

[image]

This will return `undefined` when no event is attached to the element.

Note that this should be a **single element**, so for a class you should use:

```
$._data($('.class')[0], "events")
```

*Which only select the first element with that class, instead of all the elements with that class.*

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jDC9J/)

---

Source: [jQuery find events handlers registered with an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object)