# Keep bootstrap accordion open on click

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

We have the following in my AngularJS view. The issue is that when a user clicks in the textbox a second time, it closes the accordion, I want it to stay open until a different accordion is opened.

```
<div class="col-xs-7 panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="" data-target="#collapseOne" class="collapsed">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="vm.Whatever" placeholder="Whatever">
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                lorem ipsum....
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

To Clear up confusion, I've changed it to the following

```
<accordion class="col-xs-7 panel-group" id="accordion">
    <accordion-group>
        <accordion-heading>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="vm.Whatever" placeholder="Whatever">
        </accordion-heading>
        <div>
            lorem ipsum....
        </div>
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

Comment: Why is this related to AngularJS?

Comment: So I hopefully don't get a bunch of 'do this in jquery' responses

Comment: I don't get it... Is it the angular-ui bootstrap's accordion? Cause you don't seem to be using it

Comment: How are you instantiating the accordion without using jQuery? You have no custom directives.

Comment: is it clearer now that I'm using `<accordion*>` elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `accordion*` directive from angular-ui, you can only prevent the toggle if you set `is-disabled` (here's the [src](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/0.12.1/src/accordion/accordion.js#L83)). But probably an easier approach is to force the `is-open` variable to be `true` on click:

```
<accordion-group is-open="openA" ng-click="openA = true">
  <accordion-heading>
    whatever
  </accordion-heading>

</accordion-group>

<accordion-group is-open="openB" ng-click="openB = true">
  <accordion-heading>
    whatever
  </accordion-heading>

</accordion-group>
```

Comment: That's having no effect here as well...it's still opening and closing on each click.

Comment: I think the issue is we have  0.10.0

Comment: @CaffGeek, right - 0.10.0 doesn't have `is-disabled`. I edited the question with what is probably even a better approach

Comment: @CaffGeek, did this address your question?

Comment: Possibly, I'll be back at the office Monday to try it out

Answer (score 0):

This may be a duplicate of [How to prevent an angular-bootstrap dropdown from closing (Unbind Event which was bound by a directive)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23698316/584846)

```
<accordion-group ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
```

Comment: Why would you post a duplicate answer instead of voting to close the question as duplicate?

Comment: That change is having no effect.

Comment: Maybe place the `ng-click` on the `<input>` element?

Answer (score 0):

can implements many div of id `#accordion{{$i}}` each accordion only having `1 child` that referring 1 its parent

```
    <div class=""
         id="accordion{{$i}}">

        <h3 class="" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#collapse{{$strength->id}}"
            aria-expanded="true"
            aria-controls="collapse{{$strength->id}}" class="mb-0">
            Hai Im the clickable
        </h3>

        <div id="collapse{{$i}}"
             class="collapse"
             aria-labelledby="heading{{$i}}"
             data-parent="#accordion{{$i}}">
            <p>Hai Im the collapsible content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```