# How to first get ID and then use it in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do this:

1. Get ID from `data-status` attribute of `.addlink` and store it as `post_id`.
2. Clicking on `.mar-post_id` will toggle `.finished-reading` from `#statusfor-post_id`

I have the following code but it does not work. What could I be doing wrong?

```
jQuery(".addlink").click(function(){
    var post_id = jQuery(this).attr("data-status");
    jQuery(".mar-"+post_id).click(function() {
        jQuery("#statusfor-"+post_id).toggleClass( "finished-reading" );
    });
});
```

The following is the HTML markup.

```
<div class="simple-card" id="statusfor-12">
<div class="simple-card-actions">
<span class="wpfp-span">
<a class="addlink mar-12" href="#" data-status="12">Click me to toggle</a>
</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maremp/hgz4mwgy/) from your code to test this out and it works as you'd expect.

But there could be a problem if you have different html structure, i.e. if `.mar-*` is nested inside `.addlink`. The problem in this case is that you add new click event every time, so if you click `.mar-*`, you'll trigger `.addlink`'s click event, adding new click event listener, so the toggle will trigger multiple times.

It's hard to guess how to fix this without seeing full page structure, best thing that I can suggest is take a look at [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

---

After question update:

Here's a dirty hack, which adds only one listener to the element: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maremp/hgz4mwgy/1/). Keep in mind that `_data` works in jQuery 1.8+, prior to that it was available as `.data` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518441/1276128)).

I wouldn't recommend to use this, as `_data` is private property, so this might break in future.

You could also use vanilla JS [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener), without `useCapture` attribute.

*Better approach:*

One thing that comes to mind is changing structure of your elements or change when you add click events. It's a bad practice to add an event every time you click something, I would recommend you to add all click listeners as soon as the element is added to page (on domready/window load or when you receive data from ajax call) and then don't change the events after that.

Comment: Exactly, `.mar-*` is inside .addlink. I will take a look at `.one()`. Thank you!

Comment: Mind that `.one` executes only once, so only first click will work and then it will be disabled. Only way for inner click function to be called again is adding `.one` listener again.

Comment: I've updated my question, I hope this is more helpful to you.

Comment: it works nicely but as you can see, first click is required for the `post_id` to get stored and only then the toggle works.

Comment: I know that, that's why I've recommended you to add click events as soon as you create elements, not after user clicks inside `.addlink`

Comment: OK, I think I'd rather shuffle the markup as that is the easiest approach. So, I'll mark this as an answer!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67760/discussion-between-maremp-and-sam).