# How to find executed function name on specific event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events, trace

I'm using a jQuery plugin in my application and now I need to develop this plugin for my need. At this time, I want to know For example **which function call on clicking some buttons**. For example, suppose the plugin had produced a `<button id="test">Test</button>`. I want to catch function that call on click on this button. Is there any way or tools for doing that?

**Update:**

Based on  **nanndoj** suggested link, probably `jQuery._data( elem, "events" );` can solve my problem. But how can I use that method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and solved my problem:

```
$.each($._data($("#elementID")[0], "events"), function(i, event) {
      console.log(i);
      $.each(event, function(j, h) {
           console.log(h.handler);
      });
});
```

Here is the fiddle link that helped me: http://jsfiddle.net/9n6gh/.

So many thanks to **nanndoj** for his help.