# detach and reattach event listeners

Tags: jquery, event-listener

Is there a way to detach and reattach event listeners assuming I don't know the function that was attached in the first place?

```
//Unknown click function
$(target).click(function(e){
    //some function
});

//code to detach click function
$(target).mousedown(function(e){
    if(/*something*/){
        //The next line does not work. What could be done instead?
        this.clickFunction = $(target).click;
        $(target).off("click");
    }
});

//code to reattach click function
$(target).mouseup(function(e){
    if(this.clickFunction){
        $(target).click(this.clickFunction);
        this.clickFunction = null;
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you event try something before you add a question which doesn't even have the right syntax.

Comment: I don't know what to try that is why I asked the question

Comment: `$(..).onmouseup(...)` is not a valid statement. `$(..).mouseup(...)` can be used. But `$(..).on('mouseup',...)` is a much better option. See the documentation http://api.jquery.com/on/ and http://api.jquery.com/off/
to see how you can bind and unbind properly.

Comment: Sorry I fixed it. That wasn't the important part of the question. That code was just to illustrate the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery saves the event functions internally as:

```
$._data(target, "events")
```

Where "target" is a DOM element not a jQuery object.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518441/806777

So the example code would be:

```
//Unknown click function
$(target).click(function (e) {
    //some function
});

//code to detach click function
$(target).mousedown(function (e) {
    if (/*something*/) {
        this.clickFunctions = [];
        var click = $._data(target, "events").click;
        for(var i = 0; i < click.length; i++) {
            this.clickFunctions.push(click[i].handler);
        }
        $(target).off("click");
    }
});

//code to reattach click function
$(target).mouseup(function (e) {
    if (this.clickFunctions) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.clickFunctions.length; i++) {
            $(target).click(this.clickFunctions[i]);
        }
        this.clickFunctions = null;
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/UziTech/176fzorn/

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery `unbind()` like as below to detach,

```
$(target).unbind('click');
$(target).unbind('mousedown');
$(target).unbind('mouseup');
```

And you can reattach using `bind()`

```
$(target).bind('click',function(){
  //some code
});
 $(target).bind('mousedown',function(){
//some code
});
 $(target).bind('mouseup',function(){
 //some code
});
```

Comment: I don't see how this reattaches the click function

Comment: This is wrong. I accidentally up-voted it. `bind('onmousedown')` are you serious? Did you mean `bind('mousedown')`

Comment: To use this you would need to know the code to rebind it to the event. How could you rebind the function without knowing the code?

Comment: How can you make the code into a single function without knowing the code? As in this is a plugin that is trying to detach and reattach a click event. How can the plugin find out the code for the click event?

Comment: This isn't helpful though.  Say I'm using a UI element from jQuery UI, and I want my event handler to fire before theirs because I might want to prevent it.  I'd want to detach their event, attach mine, and then reattach theirs.  I don't know their code, and shouldn't have to.