# hashchange event not being fired on mobile Chrome (Wordpress site)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-events, hashchange

In my Wordpress site, I've created a Modal shortcode, which opens a modal when the modal's "name" is in the hash part of the location.
For instance `/#contact-us` will open my "contact us" modal.

To do this I have a `hashchange` event listener on the window, using jQuery, as so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on('hashchange', function () {
        openModal();
    });        
});
```

On my laptop, this works pretty fine.

The problem is that when I try it on my mobile phone (Nexus 5 - Chrome & Firefox), and even when I use Chrome's devtools emulator, when clicking on an anchor with a `href="#contact-us"`, it won't work - The hash in the url changes but the event handler is not being called.

The weird thing is if I manually add a hash to the url, the event handler will be called.

I thought there might be another handler that is stopping the propagation or something like that, so I tried using jQuery's `_data` function (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518441)) to see if there are any handlers, but couldn't find any.

So I guess my question is, why isn't this working? and what else can I do to find out where the event is "getting lost"?