# .unbind when no .bind has been done previously

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Is there any risk of doing that? Example:

```
if (someCondition) {
   angular.element($window).bind('scroll', myHandler);
}

$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    angular.element($window).unbind('scroll', myHandler);
});
```

Of course I could do

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    if (someCondition) {
        angular.element($window).unbind('scroll', myHandler);
    }
});
```

But I don't know if it's necessary. I've tested without the `someCondition` condition and "it works", but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: I think angular add DOM property ng339, so you may check that as a workaround

Comment: Well, not sure I get it. Workaround? What I've posted actually works, just wanted to know if it's ok to do it in that way. Thanks.

Comment: There is no error from unbinding a handler that is not bond, not 100% kosher, but it won't cause any errors. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2518441/227299

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its absolutely fine, there is no need to check the condition while destruction of scope.

```
if (someCondition) {   angular.element($window).bind('scroll', myHandler);}

$scope.$on('$destroy', function() { angular.element($window).unbind('scroll', myHandler);});
```