# How to find event attached to a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, dom, firebug

Firebug only show HTML and CSS by default. How can I find events attached to a DOM element? I want to inspect a theme but I don't know how I find events attached to a DOM element because there is no debugger.

Firebug executes code without showing anything. Is there a way to show those events?

Comment: In chrome's dev tool, goto "Elements" tab. On right you'll see Styles, Computed, Event Listeners.... There you'll get all binded listeners for each event type, find what you need there.

Comment: The questioner asks for the functionality in Firebug, not the Chrome DevTools.

Answer (score 0):

There is a universal solution for this

- Hit F12 to open Dev Tools
- Click the Sources tab
- On right-hand side, scroll down to "Event Listener Breakpoints", and expand tree
  Click on the events you want to listen for. *Interact with the target element, if they fire you will get a break point in the debugger

Comment: Your answer refers to the Chrome DevTools, not Firebug.

Comment: @SebastianZartner - Great But I love Chrome for everything.

Comment: I was looking for the same solution but using Chrome developer tools. Worked like a charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can get a list of all registered events of an HTML element (not a jQuery object or selector) by executing

```
jQuery._data( elem, "events" );
```

in your firebug console.

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518441) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug 2 has an [*Events* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Events_Side_Panel) within the [*HTML* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel) listing all events attached to an element.

[image: *Events* side panel within Firebug]

It even displays wrapped listeners. I.e. if you're using a library like jQuery, you normally don't want to see the event handler function of jQuery but your own one, which is shown prefixed by a >.