# Will jQuery throw an error when using off() for undefined event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, jquery-events

I am using jQuery 1.10.2, but would also like to know the solution for the most modern version if it is not the same.

I have a JavaScript file that will add and remove some custom events.

```
$(window).on('clicked_button', function(event) {
    // Do stuff
});

if (someCriteria) {
    $(window).off('clicked_button');
}

if (otherCriteria) {
    $(window).trigger('clicked_button');
}
```

I know that you can [loop through the events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object) in the data object to check if the event is already bound or not, but is that necessary? I don't care if the event is already bound or not, I just want to make sure it won't be bound after `someCriteria` is met.

When I run `$(window).off('clicked_button');` in the js console on Firefox, it just returns the window object. Can I assume then that the `off()` function will not throw an error if the event isn't already bound? I'd prefer to just use `off()` and let it silently fail, than having to loop through the bound events before unbinding it.

I would need this to work for the modern browsers and IE 9+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the jQuery API documentation, [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) was added in version 1.7.  `$(window).off('clicked_button')` will fail silently even if the custom `'clicked_button'` event was never bound to an element.

Similarly, calling `$(window).off()` will remove all event handlers without error, even if none have been bound.

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find in the docs where it explicitly said that it would throw an error or not.