# How to properly intercept jquery click handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a generic plugin, that has the following logic:

1. Look for #add-to-cart button Save previously attached click handler(Idon't have access to this code)
2. Attach plugin's click handler, that shows popup with email opt-in.
3. After successful opt-in trigger the original click handler.

I don't have access to the website's code, so I have to make a generic solution.

My implementation looks like this:

```
var $addToCart = $('#add-to-cart');
var origClickHandler = $addToCart.click;
$addToCart.off('click').on('click', function() {
    // code to show opt-in popup ...
    var $optinButton = /* ... */ ;
    $optinButton.click(function() { // binding opt-in button to original click handler
        origClickHandler.apply($addToCart);
    });
});
```

But I'm getting error on the line `origClickHandler.apply($addToCart)`:

```
jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: this.on is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.n.fn.(anonymous function) (http://www.myshop.com/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4:4893)
```

**Update**

- My intent is to bind my plugin's click handler that will further call the original click handler(and not replace the original click handler entirely)
- I tried to replace `.apply()` with `.call()` and got the same error.
- I tried to replace `origClickHandler.apply($addToCart);` with `$addToCart.off('click').on('click', origClickHandler); $addToCart.click();` and got the same error as well

**Update 2**

I accomplished what I wanted by cloning the button and hiding the original button:

```
var $addToCart = $('#add-to-cart');
var $addToCartClone = $addToCart.clone(false); // false - not copying the events and handlers
$addToCart.before($addToCartClone).hide();
$addToCartClone.click(function() {
    // code to show opt-in popup ...
    var $optinButton = /* ... */ ;
    $optinButton.click(function() { // binding opt-in button to original click handler
        $addToCart.click();
    });
});
```

It seems like when I call `.off('click')` jquery disables the click handler that was attached and I can't use it anymore. I don't know the reason, but it should work.

I will leave the question unanswered in case anyone finds the reason why original click handler stops working after calling `.off('click')`.

Comment: `$('#add-to-cart').click(function() { .... } );` works quite well.  Are you trying to override an existing click handler ?  If so, you can do `$('#add-to-cart').off();` or for older jquery `$('#add-to-cart').unbind('click');` before binding to your new method.

Comment: @KraangPrime He doesn't want to stop the old click handler completely, just do an extra check first.

Comment: But how are you going to check if a person has already signed up? Or are you just going to annoy everyone, all the time? :)

Comment: @Barmar, the first block i provided does that. I gave the additional code to remove the handler with an "**Are you trying to override an existing click handler ? If so, you can do**" following the directions on how to append a new click handler to the same object/event.

Comment: @KraangPrime I see I misunderstood. What he actually seems to want is to bind a different button's click handler to the original button's click handler.

Comment: @Barmar - that is not what I am getting out of this, although it is not outside the scope of possibility that you could be correct -- and the question/intent is not clear.  -- If that is in fact the case, then this is a Possible duplicate of [jQuery find events handlers registered with an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object)

Comment: You should be using `.call()`, not `.apply()`. `.apply()` needs a second argument containing an array of arguments.

Comment: @Barmar I changed `.apply()` to `.call()` and got the same error.