# Cannot read function of undefined

Tags: jquery, function, events, plugins, undefined

I'm trying to create another event type extending the $.event.special object. Because I need to change an element different from input type. The problem is that when I launch the page the console gives me this error:

main.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mutationsLists' of undefined

The script is this:

```
(function($){

 $.event.special.changeElement = {
    eventType: 'changeElement',
    mutationObserver : new MutationObserver($.event.special.changeElement.mutationsLists),

    setup: function(data, namespaces) {
      var config = { attributes: true, childList: true };
      $.event.special.changeElement.mutationObserver.observe(this, config);
    },

    teardown: function(namespaces) {
      $.event.special.changeElement.mutationObserver.disconnect();
    },

    handler: function(event) {
      event.type = $.event.special.changeElement.eventType;
      return $.event.dispatch.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    mutationsLists : function(mutationsList) {
      for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
          if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
              console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
          }
          else if (mutation.type == 'attributes') {
              console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
          }
      }
    }

  }

})(jQuery);
```

I checked and it looks that $.event.special.changeElement is defined, but looks undefined when a call its members...

Answer (score 0):

`mutationLists` is a property of `$.event.special.changeElement` which is a function. Having properties as functions of an object acts as a function *expression* meaning that is is not defined until the code is reached. For an example of this, see this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLh2y7za/3/).

You will see in that fiddle that `firstFunction` can call `secondFunction` as it is defined before it. However, `secondFunction` cannot call `thirdFunction` as it is not defined before `firstFunction` is invoked.

For a rectification to your issue, define the function `mutationLists` before you define the property `mutationObserver`.

Comment: I tried this too, it doesn't work. The only thing that works it's to call mutationList as an external function.

Comment: As you are within the same scope of the object to access the reference to the function, you should use 'this' keyword. For example, this.mutationLists

Comment: I made this too... when I made a console.log of this I saw that is a window object...

Comment: Why is it needed to create an instance of MutationObserver within the object? As you mentioned, why can you not just instantiate it after the object had been defined?

Comment: Oh ok. But how can I get the handle to launch it???

I tried with $._data(this, "events") but how can I get the handle that I pass with $(...).on('changeElement', f....)?

I need to launch f after the mutation of the dom...

Comment: You mentioned when you logged 'this', a window object was returned, correct? By this definition (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object), '$._data(this, "events")' would not work as the 1st argument to '_data' needs to be a HTML element