# How to know about the event listeners attached to a UI element in Angular 6?

Tags: angular

Let's say I have this simple rendered `div` element in browser:

```
<div class="contact">
   <!-- info here -->
</div>
```

And I don't have access to the source code of Angular. Is there a way to find out what event listeners are attached to `div.contact` element?

Comment: There's no way in JS you can get an event listener bound to an HTMLElement, so I'd say no. Plus, the code of your app is compiled, meaning your functions will be called `a` or `b`, which won't tell you what method is ran.

Comment: You can examine event listeners when debugging, but I don't think you can get the listeners programmatically. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/events#view_event_listeners_registered_on_dom_elements

Comment: In jQuery in the old days we had [such capability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object)