# Potential jQuery Listener Race Condition - Maybe Chrome Dev Tools Related

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools, race-condition

Buckle in, this may be a longer ride than expected...

Note: all listeners are delegated to the 'body' and all triggered events are on the 'body' as well.

**Intended On-Page-Load Flow**

1. Create selector with id #selectorA
2. Register listener for #selectA value changed (listener1) that triggers ("aChanged")
3. If condition X, register listener for aChanged that reloads the parent page (listener2)
4. Register listener for aChanged that applies CSS changes to #selectorA (listener3)

**Intended On-Change Flow**

1. User updates #selectA value -> $.trigger("aChanged")
2. listener1 hears aChanged -> If condition, then reload whole page
3. listener2 hears aChanged -> $.load() a div on page
4. listener3 hears aChanged -> update some #selectA element's css classes (not the elements, just their css)

My intent is that if on-change-flow step 2 reloads the whole page, the other listeners can do whatever they want - or fail, I don't care because the page is being reloaded anyway. My assumption is that if the page is reloading, the other listeners can't affect the div/CSS of the now-loading/newly-loaded page.

**My problem**

Sometimes, but inconsistently seldom, when switching #selectA between two or more options that satisfy condition X (reload page condition), the listeners stop listening - or the aChanged event isn't fired.

When logging to the console I noticed that any time the listeners are about to fail (when they are registered prior to not hearing anything) that the order of loadPage - registerAllListeners changes, and instead of the console logs coming from the index page, they come from a VMxyz identifier (chrome's dev tool "this script isn't associated with a URL" identifier). If it's about to fail, most of the "registering listener" console logs come before chrome's "Navigated to https://..." log - all of these logs coming from the VMxyz identifier.

**My Question(s)**

1. I sort of understand chrome's dev tools VMxyz identifier, but I could use help understanding why - some of the time - these console.log() statements come from the actual page and why they sometimes come from the VMxyz.
2. I can't wrap my head around why the listeners would stop working sometimes. To me it seems that even if the page did reload mid-listener action, the page would just create the new listeners anyways.
3. If someone has a recommendation on how I could further debug this, or fix it completely (please) I would appreciate it.

Comment: Can you provide a code example where you're consistently encountering the issue?

Comment: I am afraid I can not. Largely because it's not even consistent in my dev. environment, but also because it seems to be related to browser redirects and timing, which I have been unable to reproduce at all outside of my dev environment.

Mostly looking for information and how I might progress in debugging this.