# find all listeners of a DOM element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser-console

I have a program which runs just fine in the console, because I paste it into the browser console. It uses the console's function `getEventListeners` which is very handy to get the handlers for specific events. However, I would like to do this for a regular javascript (without console). For example, in the console the code looks like this:

```
someEl.addEventListener('mousedown', () => { alert('mousedown') });

const mouseDownHandler = getEventListeners(someEl).mousedown[0].listener;
```

How can I do the same thing without the console? 
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: I have my reasons :) I'm doing tests with WebDriverIO and need to do some interaction with the DOM. It is so much easier if I could directly call the handler, but I'm probably just lazy :). On the other hand, I find this also an interesting case! Maybe I can start chrome with some options which make these debug functions available?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object seems this is what you are looking for

Comment: @Ananthu that topic is about `jQuery`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node-when-debugging-or-from-the-javascript/3426352

Here is a javascript only way of getting things. It also seems like a bit over overhead to set all that up.
answer by Aiden Waterman will get you started

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if you can modify the `addEventListener` function and then load the page.

Comment: I've tested the suggested solution from @Gauthier and it works as long as I first change the url, than modify `EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener`: Like this: `browser.url('....');browser.execute(....)`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, I have encountered similar issues and seems you finally have your answer. Could you please share a little bit more about how you solve the problem?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74895101/how-to-access-event-listeners-of-element-using-selenium