# click() calls the click function not returns the click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm in day 1 of a learning java script MOOC.

We're looking at simple jQuery examples.

Right off there's something I don't understand.

An expression such as `$("#xyz").html()` returns the text in the element.  For example if
the corresponding html was `<h1 name=xyz>hello world</h1>`,  then `$("#xyz").html()` evaluates to the string "hello world".   I hope I understand this so far. And `$("#xyz").html("new text")` sets the text to `"new text"` so that the next call to `$("#xyz").html()` returns `"new text"`.

And, the expression `$("#xyz").click(function (){42})` sets the click function to a function which will return `42`.   However, the presenter of the course claims without explanation that `$("#xyz").click()` calls the click function and returns `42`.  I would expect that `$("#xyz").click()` returns a function, not a number.

Am I confused?  What's the logic here?

Answer (score 3):

`.click` is *overloaded*. It's a bit confusing. You can use it to either *call* a click handler, or to *add* a click handler.

If you pass it a function, it will add a click handler. If you don't pass it anything, it'll invoke click handlers.

```js
// Add a click handler
$('button').click(() => { console.log('clicked'); });

// Invoke a click handler
$('button').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click</button>
```

To make things clearer, I'd recommend using the way jQuery recommends to attach handlers nowadays, using `.on`, and to trigger handlers with `.trigger`:

```js
// Add a click handler
$('button').on('click', () => { console.log('clicked'); });

// Invoke a click handler
$('button').trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click</button>
```

It's more intuitive than the overloaded `.click` and is more generalizable to other events.

> However, the presenter of the course claims without explanation that $("#xyz").click() calls the click function and returns 42. I would expect that $("#xyz").click() returns a function, not a number.

Neither of these is correct:

- The callback doesn't `return` anything, and isn't using the implicit return of an arrow function, so the 42 is inaccessible to anything outside the handler
- Even if the 42 was returned, `.click` does not return what the handler returns, but it returns the jQuery collection it was called on. For example, you can do

```
$('.someElement')
  .click(clickHandler)
  .addClass('clickable');
```

to add a click handler and also add a class to an element.

Comment: And how can I get the click function?  I.e., get back the function someone most recently passed to `.click(...)` ?

Comment: Your code uses jQuery 3.3.1, I see that the MOOC is using jQuery 1.11.3.   I'll continue with the MOOC, as I've already paid, to understand the concepts.  But I imagine lots has changed since 1.11.3.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518441 It's possible, but kinda weird. If the callback is really needed, I think it'd make a bit more sense to store it in a variable first, than to go through `events` to retrieve it later.