# How to get all event listeners binded to specific element in JavaScript and change them to return altKey true?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener

Is it possible to get all event listeners from a target element, delete them, and create a mock one, but passed with the event being {altKey: true}? For example,

```
function getListeners(element){

//find all click listeners and return an array of the functions being called in the listener, e.g. ["function(e){alert('Is alt being pressed: '+e.altKey);}","doSomething", etc]

//delete all of these listeners

/*using the returned value, 

for(var i = 0; i<returnedValue.length; i++){
document.addEventListener('click',eval(returnedValue[i]);

//somehow edit the function so it’s parameter is {altKey:true}, or a modified event object, with altKey set to true, like e.altKey = true; function(e){}

//POSSIBLE SOLUTION: “e.altKey = true; ” + returnedValue[i]

}
*/
}
```

Comment: There's no built-in way to retrieve or replace event listeners.

Comment: How about with jQuery?

Comment: While it's not a documented API, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object

Comment: So this doesen't work for normal event handlers?

Comment: Only jQuery made?

Comment: Right. Since JS doesn't provide a way to access regular event listeners, how would jQuery get them?

Comment: if you created yourself the event listeners you can delete them. If it's coming from somewhere else, javascript can't find attached events. A trick: you can copy the element, remove the original, all events attached are going to be deleted as well. Attach your event listener to the copy