# How can I get an event listener in DevTools when creating jQuery alias?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-devtools, jquery-events, event-listener, firefox-developer-tools

I can't get an event listener in Chrome DevTools and Firefox DevTools when creating a different alias instead of jQuery to use jQuery.noConflict

I would like to know how to get event listeners in Chrome DevTools or Firefox DevTools when using jQuery noConflict.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>

<!--
external js file that I cannot change.
<script src="external.js"></script>
-->
<script>
//Contents of external.js
  let $j = $.noConflict(true);
  (function($) {
    $(function() {
      init();
    });
    function init() {
      $('.click').on('click', function() {
        console.log('click');
        return false;
      });
    }
  })($j);
  $j = null;
</script>

<a href="#" class="click">click</a>
```

[image: DevTools]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object for how you get jQuery event handlers. Since you're using `noConflict`, use `$j` instead of `$` or `jQuery`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am very sorry. The code was wrong so I changed it.

Comment: Before the code change, the handler was displayed by typing the following in the console.
`$j._data($j('a').get(0), 'events').click[0].handler`

Comment: Why did you reassign `$j`? Now there's no way to access that version of jQuery outside the anonymous function.

Comment: The reason is unknown because it is an external file.There's no way to access it. . . I understand. Thank you for your teachings.

Answer (score 1):

Set a breakpoint after `$j = $.noConflict(true);`. Then you can manually assign some other variable to hold a reference to this version of jQuery:

```
myJQuery = $j;
```

Then you can use `myJQuery` in place of `$` or `jQuery` to access the shadowed version of jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I couldn't figure out how to get the event handler.`myJQuery._data(myJQuery('a').get(0), 'events').click[0].handler
` was not available.