# how to unbind all event using jquery 

Tags: jquery, events, unbind

i can use this code to remove click event,

```
$('p').unbind('click')
```

but , has some method to remove all event  ?

has a method named `unbindAll` in jquery  ?

thanks

Comment: It would be worth changing your accepted answer from Nick's to totallyNotLizards' because `.unbind()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You can call [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) without parameters to do this:

```
$('p').unbind();
```

From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/):

> In the simplest case, with no arguments, `.unbind()` removes all handlers attached to the elements.

Comment: If 'p' has some child elements, will this statement unbind listeners on those too?

Comment: Accroding to the document, from jQuery 3.0, `.unbind()` has been deprecated. It was superseded by the `.off()` method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.

Answer (score 90):

As of jQuery 1.7, [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) and [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) are the preferred methods to bind and unbind event handlers.

So to remove all handlers from an element, use this:

```
$('p').off();
```

or for specific handlers:

```
$('p').off('click hover');
```

And to add or bind event handlers, you can use

```
$('p').on('click hover', function(e){
    console.log('click or hover!');
});
```

Comment: If you want to _remove every binding from your page_ you can call `$(document).add('*').off();`.

Comment: $(document).add('ID_OF_THE_ELEMENT').off(); helped me .. thanks @flu

Comment: @Moitt Glad I could help. Please note, that in your case you could have used `$('#ELEMENT_ID').off()` directly instead.

Comment: Yeah i forgot to mention '#' <-- hash sign .. MY BAD grrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr... thanks @flu

Comment: @Moitt Yes, that too ;) But I was talking about the `$(document).add(...)` part. You don't need the document in your node list. If you simply want to remove all events on one particular element you know the ID of, then you can use `$('#ELEMENT_ID').off()` right away (nothing added in front of it).

Answer (score 3):

To remove all event bindings from all elements including document use :

```
$(document).off().find("*").off();
```

Answer (score 2):

@jammypeach is right about on & off being the accepted methods to use.  Unbind sometimes ends up creating weird behaviors (e.g. not actually unbinding events correctly).

To unbind all elements within the body, find them all and for each one turn off the click handler (what was the old unbind):

```
$("body").find("*").each(function() {
    $(this).off("click");
});
```

Also see how to save the events that you've turned off in [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516265/jquery-unbind-event-handlers-to-bind-them-again-later).