# jquery: Cant unbind hover event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, unbind

My continue button has a hover event that tells you why it's disabled. The only problem is I can't remove the hover event when I enable the button....

**this works**

```
function disable_continue_button(){
    $('#frame_2 > .next')
        .addClass('faded tt')
        .hover(function(){
            $hovered = $(this);
            //tooltip?
            tip = $('.tip.notification.information');
            tip.find('div').html($hovered.attr('tt'));
            tip.fadeIn(150);
        },
        function() {
            tip.hide();   
        })
        .mousemove(function(e) {
            var mousex = e.pageX +40; //Get X coodrinates
            var mousey = e.pageY -20; //Get Y coordinates
            tip.css({top: mousey, left: mousex });
        });    
}
```

**this doesn't work**

```
function enable_continue_button(){
    $('#frame_2 > .next')        
        .unbind('mouseenter mouseleave mousemove')
        .removeClass('faded tt');    
}
```

the classes are removed ok, but the hover tooltip is not removed...

Comment: Works fine for me (unbinding hover via unbinding `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`) in which context are you calling `enable_continue_button()` ? Btw your `addClass` function is wrong, you should remove the comma. Based on that, are you sure that `faded` and  `tt` are added as classes? Maybe calling `nable_continue_button()` fails *and* the clases are not added so it just seems they got removed.

Comment: @felix - Sorry comma was a typo here on SO. Weird it's working for you!

Comment: Ok. See here http://jsfiddle.net/ebpM3/ So you can definitely unbind `hover` this way (the text does not turn red). Do you get any error message and are you sure that the classes are removed (i.e. `enable_continue_button` is called)?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try unbinding mouseenter, mouseleave, mouseover and mouseout.

```
$('#frame_2 > .next').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave mouseover mouseout');
```

*EDIT:*

Unbinding just mouseenter and mouseleave is sufficient.

Here's **[an example](http://jsfiddle.net/q466v/)** to show it working. When the above 4 events are unbound, the tooltip functionality is removed.

`.hover(fnEnter, fnLeave)` is essentially shorthand for `.mouseenter(fnEnter).mouseleave(fnLeave)`.

Since not all browsers support these two events natively, (if I recall correctly, only IE does), `mouseenter()` maps to `mouseover()` and `mouseleave()` maps to `mouseout()`, with some additional logic in each case to emulate the events.

Comment: Just mouseenter/mouseleave is enough. These are jQuery events (unlike hover - you can check that by inspecting jQuery.event.special), so even if the browser does not have a native mouseenter event, that is the name the event handler will be bound to.

Comment: Hi you're example definitely works, so there must be something wrong with my code somewhere. It's wierd my `enable_continue_button()` function is definitely removing the classes but not unbinding the tooltip...

Answer (score 0):

This related question may help you unbind everything, and then you could rebind what you need? [how to unbind all event using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569393/how-to-unbind-all-event-using-jquery)

Comment: Not sure, but it may be a place to start and work backwards. You could also try using jQuery's `.live()` and tie the events to the classes you are removing. That should unbind the events when you remove the classes. http://api.jquery.com/live/