# $(document).off() doesn't remove any events from the document

Tags: jquery, angularjs, event-listener, jquery-events

I'm running this snippet of jQuery to remove all event listeners from my ui-router based angular app, but it doesn't seem to do anything? Is it an illegal operation?

```
$rootScope
    .$on('$stateChangeStart', 
        function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
            console.log("Going to remove event listeners"); // this fires
            $(document).off();
    });
```

Comment: I also tried running it in the chrome dev console, with no errors. I still see all the events under Elements tab >> "Event Listeners"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to unbind all event using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569393/how-to-unbind-all-event-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you need to select the elements specifically in order to remove event handlers from them. You can remove all events from an object with `.unbind()`, but I don't believe you can do this with the whole page.
[See this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569393/how-to-unbind-all-event-using-jquery)

Comment: the events are registered on the document though based on the screenshot? http://i.stack.imgur.com/Rea95.png

Comment: Anyway ive tried doing this too and it doesnt seem to work? $("html").off() or $("body").off()

Comment: Yes, I see that. Well, someone with greater knowledge than me is going to have to take this one. :D

Comment: Just did - no luck :/

Comment: Are you adding the event handlers to the document when you load the page? I mean, are you doing something like this, `$(document).on('click', function(){})`?

Comment: The events are being created by some third party lib and are not being removed properly. I am trying to remove these without messing with the library code.