# How to unbind all events inside element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dom-events

I'm trying to `unbind` / `off` all events of every element inside one element. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569393/how-to-unbind-all-event-using-jquery) solution but it doesn't work. The only thing worked was `$(document).add('*').off();` but this is not what I need.

I made a short example, but there are more elements and events. 
Why it isn't working this code?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on("click", "#contentWithEvents button", function() {
        console.log("Clicked");
    });

    $(document).on("mouseenter", "#contentWithEvents li div", function() {
        console.log("Hovered");
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#unbind", function() {
        contentToBeReplaced = $("#contentWithEvents");
        contentToBeReplaced.find("*").each(function() {
            $(this).off();
        });
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header></header>

<main id="contentWithEvents">

    <button>Click event</button>
    <button>Click event</button>
    <button>Click event</button>
    
    <ul>
      <li><div>Hover event</div></li>
      <li><div>Hover event</div></li>
    </ul>
    
</main>

<button id="unbind">Unbind all events</button>

<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Because it is delegated. So you delegate on document but unbind on element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of delegating document events with `$(document)` why not delegate the elements directly with the selectors containing parent id and element type. This would help to unbind the events of those elements using [`off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) (specific events: `.off('mouseenter')` or all events: `.off()`)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#contentWithEvents button").on("click", function() {
    console.log("Clicked");
  });

  $("#contentWithEvents li div").on("mouseenter", function() {
    console.log("Hovered");
  });

  $("#unbind").on("click", function() {
    contentToBeReplaced = $("#contentWithEvents");
    contentToBeReplaced.find("*").off();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header></header>

<main id="contentWithEvents">

  <button>Click event</button>
  <button>Click event</button>
  <button>Click event</button>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>Hover event</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>Hover event</div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</main>

<button id="unbind">Unbind all events</button>

<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems the best way is to delegate on class selector and then remove the class when you want to no longer respond to the events

Also I have removed the delegation on the main and button since they have an ID.
If they are dynamically generated, they do need to be delegated from nearest static container

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#contentWithEvents").on("click", ".delegated", function() {
    console.log("Clicked");
  });

  $("#contentWithEvents").on("mouseenter", ".delegated", function() {
    console.log("Hovered");
  });

  $("#unbind").on("click", function() {
    $("#contentWithEvents .delegated").removeClass("delegated");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header></header>

<main id="contentWithEvents">

  <button class="delegated">Click event</button>
  <button class="delegated">Click event</button>
  <button class="delegated">Click event</button>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="delegated">Hover event</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="delegated">Hover event</div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</main>

<button id="unbind">Unbind all events</button>

<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

it's quite simple actually you were just using the .off () command in the wrong way

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on("click", "#contentWithEvents button", function() {
        console.log("Clicked");
    });

    $(document).on("mouseenter", "#contentWithEvents li div", function() {
        console.log("Hovered");
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#unbind", function() {
        $(document).off( "click", "#contentWithEvents button" );
        $(document).off( "mouseenter", "#contentWithEvents li div" );
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header></header>

<main id="contentWithEvents">

    <button>Click event</button>
    <button>Click event</button>
    <button>Click event</button>
    
    <ul>
      <li><div>Hover event</div></li>
      <li><div>Hover event</div></li>
    </ul>
    
</main>

<button id="unbind">Unbind all events</button>

<footer></footer>
```