# move event handler with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue which is driving me crazy and as a last resort I am placing a question here.

I want to move the onclick event from an element to the onfocus event of the same element and I am using the following code:

```
$("#theElement").bind("focus", {}, $("#theElement").data("events").click);
$("#theElement").unbind("click");
```

Maybe you have guess it. IT DOES NOT WORK.

How do I make this work? I am getting a "fn.apply is not a function" message in the following piece of code from jquery 1.3.2:

```
proxy: function( fn, proxy ){
        proxy = proxy || function(){ return fn.apply(this, arguments); };
        // Set the guid of unique handler to the same of original handler, so it can be removed
        proxy.guid = fn.guid = fn.guid || proxy.guid || this.guid++;
        // So proxy can be declared as an argument
        return proxy;
    }
```

**EDIT:** I'm sorry, I should have mentioned. This comes from a plugin which does some stuff when clicking an element. I want to make the same thing when the element gets focus not when it is cliked so the simplest solution I thought off was this since I can't modify the code for the plugin.

**EDIT:** Found the problem. It is similar to what @sje397 posted in his answer, not

```
$('#theElement').data('events').click[0]
```

but

```
$('#theElement').data('events').click[3]
```

For some reason, even if only one event is registered the thing ends up as 3 (the guid in that piece of code from jquery).

Comment: It does not work because `.click()` is a function that will *bind* an event to an element. It is not the event handler itself. Now I'll check out what you could do to recall the event handler ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Unbind event handlers to bind them again later](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516265/jquery-unbind-event-handlers-to-bind-them-again-later)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest naming the event handler in the first place, like

```
$('#theElement').click(function myHandler() {
  //...
});
```

Then, you can do

```
$("#theElement").bind("focus", {}, myHandler);
$("#theElement").unbind("click");
```

This should make it more readable, as well as fixing the bug.

If you can't, then you can do:

```
// assuming yours is the first handler
var myHandler = $('#theElement').data('events').click[0]; 

$("#theElement").bind("focus", {}, myHandler);
$("#theElement").unbind("click");
```

Also not that in jQuery 1.4.3+, the key was changed to `__events__`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331076/jquery-data-no-longer-works-with-window/4331226#4331226).

Comment: I can't do that. This comes from a plugin which does some stuff when clicking an element. I want to make the same thing when the element gets focus not when it is cliked so the simplest solution I thought off was this. I am willing to accept any other way of doing it. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user9238833: i found a duplicate question. See link in comments.

Comment: is it possible to unbind() a specific handler, in case there is more than one?

Comment: Yeah, namespacing. use event.yournamespacename as the event when binding. $('#element').bind('focus.namespacename',function(){ //dostuff })

Answer (score 1):

I found out that jQuery adds the event to an element by using `.data()`, so you could do something like this to retrieve the event handler:

```
$(el).data().events.click[0].handler
```

This is not an elegant solution, but if you cannot change anything to the click handler itself, this would be the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear what it is exactly that you want to do. Do you want to bind a focus AND a click event to the same element?

```
$("#theElement").bind("focus click", function(){
    //do stuff
    $(this).unbind('focus click');
});
```

**edit**: given your clarification - you want to fake the 'click' event on focus...

```
$("#theElement").bind("focus", function(){
    $(this).trigger('click');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: This is not what he wants. The OP wants to replace the click event with a focus event. By the way, you don't need the comma to seperate the events

Comment: This does not replace the click event with focus, but it's worth a shot

Comment: Yeah you'd need to unbind the click handler on top of the above or else you might end up firing your function twice...

Comment: @calumbrodie: How about subsequent focuses? If I call onclick when onfocus trigger and unbind onclick, what do I call on subsequent focuses?