# Split up and modify an element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Here's a confusing question. I need to replace an `<input>` with a different `<input>` but I need to preserve the onclick attribute. Here's an example:

```
<input type="image" class="previous_page_img graybutton mediumbutton" src="btn_prevpage.png" onclick="Add_Search_Param('page', 1); Refine();" alt="">
```

Since I cannot change the `<input>` type to a button, I want to replace it with a button, however, I need to preserve the "onclick" attribute. So first, I'd have to break up the element. Replace it with a button and append the original onclick attribute to the new button.

So in the end, I'd have this `onclick="Add_Search_Param('page', 1); Refine();"` added to the new button. Since the onclick changes, a simple `.attr` or `.prop` function would not be sufficient. It must clone the onclick attribute. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Here's jsFiddle that does not preserve the onclick attribute but does everything else: http://jsfiddle.net/rAMcw/

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516265/jquery-unbind-event-handlers-to-bind-them-again-later ?

Comment: @pete Does it matter if I'm talking about inline JavaScript?

Comment: Try this plugin: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/copyEvents

Comment: @skybondsor a whole plugin? :(

Comment: I sometimes find a plugin that is smaller and easier to integrate than whatever I might be able to come up with. The one I linked to, for instance, is only 43 lines long and totals 4K unpacked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new button right after the input, set the input to `display: none;` (or `jQuery('#input').hide()`) and have the button onclick trigger the input's onclick (`jQuery('#button').click(function(){ jQuery('#input').trigger('click'); });`

Comment: Same way all the jQuery UI plugins work. They hide the element you selected and replace it with a pretty element, then link everything up behind the scenes.

Comment: Truth, I'm looking for a more natural solution but it was a creative idea so I like it. I made a fiddle but I may want a different solution. http://jsfiddle.net/rAMcw/1/

Answer (score 2):

You could do (i used a simple javascript function to test it)

```
<input type="image" class="previous_page_img graybutton mediumbutton" src="btn_prevpage.png" onclick="Add_Search_Param('page', 1); Refine();" alt="">

var onclick = $('.mediumbutton').attr('onclick');

var but =  $('<input/>', { type: "button", value: "pressme", onclick: onclick});

$('.mediumbutton').replaceWith(but);
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/KjBm3/

Comment: @user1090389 it works with jQuery 1.4.4 http://jsfiddle.net/KjBm3/1/ i can't test it with 1.4.2 but it should be the same

Comment: For some reason it won't work on my site, I tried it with 1.3.2 and it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

How about cloning?

```
var x = $('input').clone(true);
x.attr('type','button').addClass('previous_page_img graybutton mediumbutton').val('Previous Page');
$('input').replaceWith(x);
```

Updated **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rAMcw/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with turning the existing `input` element into a button?

```
$("input.previous_page_img").prop("type", "button").val("Previous Page");
```

jQuery 1.4.2: (set the property in plain-old JavaScript);

```
$("input.previous_page_img").val("Previous Page")[0].type = "button";
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rAMcw/3/)

Comment: Updated it for the older version.

Comment: Okay but if the element, doesn't exist on a certain page, the rest of the jQuery fails?

Comment: Then you'd have to check first to see if it exists.  Why exactly are you making a change on an element that might not exist?  Is there a reason you can't just create a button in the original HTML?

Comment: Unfortunately, my software doesn't allow me to modify core asp pages, in fear that I might comply the stability/security of the site. That's why I have to do all this. The element does not exist on certain pages, but the js files are still being called on this pages...